# Need help fixing a PHP .htaccess error after server transfer

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have many HTML files which use PHP. I remedy this by using the .htacess code ...

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
```

... and it works fine (in most cases).

I use a browser sniffer to detect which browser my users are using and if they don't use IE then I display a navigation bar. the code is here ...

```
include('http://domain/browser.php'); $browser = new Browser(); if( $browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_IE) { } else{ include('http://domain.com/bottom-nav.php'); }
```

All of this worked fine before but I just did a server transfer and now only this PHP code breaks, giving me this error.

```
Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /home/myname/public_html/index.html on line 359
```

Comment: `http://domain/` = same domain on which the script is running?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the php.ini of the new server is configured with `allow_url_fopen = off` or `allow_url_include = off`. That's why.

Answer (score 3):

The `include()` function of PHP can read files locally on your server, or in your case, from a remote server via HTTP. For security reasons some system administrators will disable that feature in PHP's configuration so `include()` can only work for local files on your server.

If the file you are including is indeed part of your existing website then use a local path instead of a remote path. For example:

```
include('/path/to/website/browser.php'); $browser = new Browser(); if( $browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_IE) { } else{ include('/path/to/website/bottom-nav.php'); }
```

Otherwise you will need to contact your system administrator and have the feature enabled.

Hope that helps